# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$ : Redis Client

Tags: apache-spark

I am using redis client for storing my constants for a project but when I am reading executing the following command and using this into sparksession. Can any body help me out in this. its a maven project
and I am using the following maven dependency

```
val sparkSession=SparkSession.builder.appName(getAppName).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    sparkSession
val r = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379)
  
def getAppName:String={
val a=r.get("xyz")
    val v=new String(a.get)
    logger.info("******** xyz ************"+ v)

v
}


I am getting following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$
    at com.hpe.cdp.common.SparkCommon$.createSparkSession(abc.scala:14)
    at com.hpe.cdp.common.SparkCommon$.readHiveDataDelta(abc.scala:20)
    at com.hpe.cdp.common.CdpEapObjectCall$.saveDataCsvHiveDelta(def.scala:16)
    at com.hpe.cdp.CdpEapObject$.main(def.scala:16)
    at com.hpe.cdp.CdpEapObject.main(def.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 5 more
```

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.redis/scala-redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redis</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-redis_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Where are you running this code? Some IDE? A cluster?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.